# Cant get out signs like ä, ö, ü from filename

Tags: php, file, upload, replace

I have the following problem: 
I created a file-upload. The uploader works fine. In the uploader i generate a new filename (without blanks, everything written in small letters, etc.).
For that i created a function. But I still have problems with the german "Umlaute" (ä, ü, ö, ß). 
When I use the function, the function didn't replace them. I always get files named like "ta??nzer.pdf".

Here is the php code:

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newname = generate_alias($temp[0]);
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = $newname.".".$temp[1];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../media/presse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

And here the function:

```
function generate_alias($text) {
# Leerzeichen an Anfang und am Ende entfernen
$text = trim($text);
# Umlaute ersetzen
$upas = Array("ä" => "ae", "ü" => "ue", "ö" => "oe", "Ä" => "Ae", "Ü" => "Ue", "Ö" => "Oe","ß" => "ss","á"=>"a","Á"=>"A","é"=>"e","è"=>"e","ê"=>"e","É"=>"E");
$text = strtr($text, $upas);
# Alles klein schreiben
$text = strtolower($text);
#Sonderzeichen entfernen
$not_allowed = array("/", "|", "\\", "_", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "!", "\"", "'", "‘", "$", "&", "?", "=", "*", "#", ";", ",", ":", ".", "<", ">", "^", "°");
$text = str_replace($not_allowed, "", $text);
# Leerräume durch Bindestrich ersetzen
$text = strtr ( $text, " ", "-" );

return $text;
}
```

I use this function also for creating alias from the article titles. The article titles comes from $_POST['title']. And there the german "Umlaute" are replaced. But not in this case - uploading a file.

Do you know why?

Comment: You might have a problem with the characters set being sent by the browser. You could look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try adding this inside your  tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also The page encoding is `UTF8,` and you have to add:

Probably not. Make sure that the php file is actually saved with utf-8 encoding.

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: Hello, i already have integrated this line: 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in my php-file. 
I opened the php file with my texteditor and saved it as utf-8. 
But the problem is not solved. Any other idea?

Comment: hi ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8') pls try with this also you can refer link to avoid this types issue http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Comment: glad to help you @fomlackner, will pls vote up my answer, so if some one has same issue they can utilize our thread.